# How do I download attachments from gmail?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api, imaplib

I was able to locate the JSON file I want to download from attachment using :

```
part.get_content_type() == "application/json"
```

But have no idea on how to actually download and save it to local directory can someone pls help?

Here is the whole method:

```
#based on Python example from 
#https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/30-Days-of-Python/blob/master/tutorial-reference/Day%209/inbox.py

import imaplib

host = 'imap.gmail.com' #inbox

def get_inbox(tempList):
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)                                      #server
    mail.login(tempList[0], tempList[2])                                #login user name, user pass
    mail.select("inbox")                                                #defualt inbox
    
    _, search_data = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')                       
    my_message = []
    
    for num in search_data[0].split():                                  
        email_data = {}
        _, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')                           #getting the msg data from gmail
        _, b = data[0]                                                  #data in bytes
        
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(b)                     

        
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == "application/json":
                pass
                           
        my_message.append(email_data)
    
    return my_message
```

Comment: this is not a question ?!?

Comment: It was but nobody replied and I figured out the answer so mind as well post the solution for those who ran into the same issue I had

Comment: Please use an answer post (e.g. you rexisting one) to present your solution.

Answer (score 0):

if the attachment is in another file type
just change the json in

```
if part.get_content_type() == "application/json"
```

to the file type you want to downlaod